# How do I handle errors in Ren'py

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm making a game using Ren'py (based on python) and most errors aren't shown, especially the errors in python code. Is there a possibility to check for possible errors at compile time and how do I get where some errors occur? If there are errors the game normally doesn't run or breaks at the a errors appearance without a message.Is there maybe a file, where they are written in or something like that? Or do I have to debug using logs everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Compile errors will be shown when you first try to compile the RPY files.  They will be put in "errors.txt" in your project directory.  Most errors are not found at compile-time, however, and will only show up once you encounter them at run-time.

You can use Lint to check for some common errors (It's called "Check Script (Lint)"), but mostly you'll have to playtest to ensure there are no errors.  Errors during playback should pop up a gray screen showing the error and traceback with the option to Ignore, Rollback, or Quit.  Is this screen not showing up for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some kind of intellisense like you have for some languages, where as you write the code the IDE shows errors, then it doesn't exist. You have to launch the game so that the code is compiled, just then Ren'py will show you errors. You can see them in the editor or in the errors.txt that Ren'Py creates. To test you python code you can launch the game and type Shift + O to open the console.